# A first encounter with the diophantine equations $P(x)=p_n\#$, where $P(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ has $\deg(P)=2$ and $p_n\#$ is a primorial: an example

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, primorial

In post I would like to ask about an example of a diophantine equation having  the form

$$P(x)=p_n\#\tag{1}$$
where $P(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a polynomial of degree $\deg(P)=2$ and $p_n\#$ denotes the primorial of order $n$, that is 
$$p_n\#=\prod_{k=1}^n p_k,$$
being $p_k$ the $k$th prime number. This is the Wikipedia's article dedicated to [Primorial.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)

Equations of the form $(1)$ were in the literature for different aritmetic functions in the corresponding RHS.

**Our problem.** We consider the solutions $(n,x)$, where $n\geq 1$ is an integer and also $x\geq 1$ is a positive integer, of $$\frac{x(x+1)}{2}=p_n\#.\tag{2}$$
One finds easily two solutions by observation $(n,x)=(2,3)$ and $(n,x)=(4,20)$.

> **Question.** Can be proven that our problem has finilety many solutions $(n,x)$? **Many thanks.**

**Remark 1 (see the comments).** Thanks to the users in the comments, now the  question can be rephrased to (see also the references to OEIS)

> *Is there* $n>4$ *such that* $8(p_n\#)+1$ *is a square number?*

I am waiting thus what work can be done to prove that the equation has finitely many solutions $(n,x)$, or at least if some user can to find a new solution (after that there are some answers I think that it is reasonable that I should to accept an answer.)

**Remark 2.** Using [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) (choose *GP* as Language) with a Pari/GP program, this (and similar) code

`for (n = 1, 200,for (x = 1, 10000, if (x*(x+1)/2==prod( k=1, n, prime(k)), print(n))))`

I cann't find more solutions. I have tried some reasonings (splitting the primorial in two factors or use the size of primorials) but these do not work.

Comment: What might help : A non-negative integer $n$ is a triangular number (that is can be written as $\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$ with non-negative integer $x$) if and only if $8n+1$ is a perfect square (To include $n=0$, $1$ must be considered to be a perfect square). Hence, the problem boils down to find out when $16\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots p+1$ is a perfect square

Comment: For the next square (if it exists) , $p_n$ must exceed $10^5$

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable comments @Peter Feel free to add your thoughts as an answer when you consider it.

Comment: For the next square, even $p_n>10^6$ must hold. It seems unlikely that there is another square, but a proof seems difficult.

Comment: Your question can be rephrased to "Is there $n>4$ such that $8(p_n\#)+1$ is square number?". The similar question such that $n>7$ and $8(p_n\#)+1$ is replaced with $4(p_n\#)+1$ looks unsolved. See: https://oeis.org/A161620 and https://oeis.org/A215659

Comment: Many thanks for your references and remark @didgogns